# GCP Cloud Composer AirFlow : is it possible to change the kubernetes configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

The goal of Google Cloud composer is to have a managed instance of AirFlow via GKE. The goal is not to have to worry about pods deployment.

In my company, an internal security scanning tool is raising a warning about AirFlow pods "Pod airflow-scheduler-XXXXX hasn't any anti affinity".

Is it even possible to take action in the Google Cloud composer side to configure an anti affinity policy ? Even if it's possible, would that be a good idea [given the fact that the goal of Google Cloud composer is supposed be a 100% managed service] ?

Comment: It may not suggested approach but depends on the tradeoffs between your requirements.

Comment: It's likely possible, but I'd advise understanding why the scanner thinks its an issue.  Sounds like it's just a warning though.  Are you Composer V1 or V2?

Comment: Composer v2.
We might be one of the only team using composer in the department. It's indeed just a warning but for some reason it's labelled "HIGH" priority...

Comment: Does this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) help you?

Comment: Thank you for providing me this link. However, it doesn't help me because my question was more about how to achieve that in the context of composer + having feedback about whether or not it was relevant to do it.